# Correct usage of jQuery .data() 

Tags: jquery, image

**PLEASE NOTE I HAVE UPDATED THIS QUESTION WITH NEW DATA AND LINKS**

I have this code based on [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data)

the code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7ZBxP/

but not here:

I get  `Error: $(this).data("orgSize") is undefined`

on line `width: $(this).data("orgSize").width,`

```
  $(".ui-tooltip img.thumb")
 .live("mouseenter",function() {
    cont_left = $(".ui-tooltip").position().left; // no container until hover 
    // save this scaled down image size for later
    $(this).data("newSize",{width:this.width,height:this.height})
    $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 1);    
    $(this).animate({
      width: $(this).data("orgSize").width,
      height: $(this).data("orgSize").height,
      left: "-=50",
      top: "-=50"
    }, "fast");
  })
```

here is where I define it:

```
    var imageObject = $('<img/>').load(function(){
      var w = this.width;
      var h = this.height;
      var orgSize = {width:w,height:h};
      var imgId = "thumb_"+p_sPubNum;
      var actualImage = $('<img/>')
         .attr("id",imgId)
         .attr("src",sOpsUrl + sImageUrl)
         .attr("alt",loadingLabel+': '+p_sPubNum)
         .addClass("thumb");             
      // set EITHER width OR height if either is > 150
      if (w<h && w>150) actualImage.attr("width",150);
      else if (w>h && h > 150) actualImage.attr("height",150);

      $('.qTip2Image').append(actualImage);
      // save original size for later    
      $("#"+imgId).data("orgSize",orgSize);

    }).error(function() {
      if ((iPos + 1) < aPublicationNumbers.length) {
        var sNextNumber = aPublicationNumbers[(iPos + 1)];
        getImage(sNextNumber, sDirection);
      }
    }).attr("src",sOpsUrl + sImageUrl);
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using jQuery to create the element and add the onload event handler?

Comment: It's better to just open a new question, and cite this one for background and context.

Comment: @TimPost: And to answer your own question with details of how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @Tim - interestingly I am now right back where I started, but with much more information so I will need to let this one continue.

Comment: @Will - the problem is exactly the same as it was. Please do NOT roll back. Thanks

Comment: @Will - Yes. I thought (and I think mplungjan thought) he had two related (but different) problems in the works.

Comment: the real issue was the much larger DOM in my real page - the fiddle worked because it was smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.qTip2Image').append(actualImage);
  // save original size for later    
$("#"+imgId).data("orgSize",orgSize); // <<<<<<<<<< too early
```

---

```
var actualImage = $('<img/>')
 .attr("id",imgId)
 .attr("src",sOpsUrl + sImageUrl)
 .attr("alt",loadingLabel+': '+p_sPubNum)
 .addClass("thumb")
 .data("orgSize",orgSize);  // <<<<<<<<<< This is much better!!!
```

Reason it worked in the fiddle was the much smaller DOM

Answer (score 0):

It gives you undefined because you are accessing the width proerty wich is undefined since you just created the elemnt!

as you can see from this fiddle the code is correct

http://jsfiddle.net/ZL4DG/

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I set the data in the onload function. That is AFTER the image has been created AND loaded.

Comment: You can see that the fiddle works. The problem might be with imgId which we don't see from where it comes from. Also you are missing a ) in your alert

Comment: the fiddle is not using a dynamically created item. What ) am I missing?

Comment: what i am saying is that if `this.witdh` is set (you can alert it to see if it is set), the only problem might lie in `$("#"+imgId)` because i don't know from where `imgId` comes from. the other parts work

Comment: You more or less were correct - not for the exact reasons you gave but due to a delay in the DOM on the actual page I have which is larger than the jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `src` of the image how do you expect it will trigger the `load` event. Attach an error `event` handler in such case. Also you have not set any width and height to the element created so it will not have any default dimensions where there is not source set.

Where is `imgId` defined in your code? Where are you setting `id` to the newly created element? In that case how will it find `$("#"+imgId)`?

Comment: Of course I am - how would the onload trigger if I didn't - updated the question just for you

Comment: Where is `id` set to the image?

Comment: Please see complete example now